# MySQL-All Subset of Values in Column

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table named causality which has 2 column (eventA,eventB) of datatype (varchar,varchar) as described below

```
  ----------------------------------------------
   eventA                |  eventB     
  ------------------------------------------------
  Wait - User            |  Resolved
  Wait                   |  Resolved
  Closed                 |  In Progress
  Wait - Vendor          |  Resolved
  Wait - Customer        |  Resolved
  Wait - Implementation  |  Assigned
  Wait - Implementation  |  Resolved
  Closed                 |  Awaiting Assignment
  Wait                   |  Assigned
  Wait - Customer        |  Awaiting Assignment
  Resolved               |  Unmatched
  Unmatched              |  In Progress
  Wait - Vendor          |  Assigned
  Wait - Customer        |  Assigned
  Wait - Implementation  |  Wait - Customer
  In Progress            |  Cancelled

  -----------------------------------------------
```

Now i want all subset of eventB in particular eventA like for Wait - Implementation of eventA column has 3 uniques values so 8 subset will be generated which are {{Assigned},{Resolved},{Wait - Customer},{Assigned,Resolved},{Assigned,Wait - Customer},{Resolved,Wait - Customer},{Assigned,Resolved,Wait - Customer},{}}

Now similarly for all values in eventA like Closed in eventA column will have 4 subset ,Wait in eventA column will have 4 subset,Wait - Vendor in eventA column will have 4 subset, Wait -Customer in eventA column will have 8 subset, In Progress in eventA column will have 2 subset, Resolved in eventA column will have 2 subset, Unmatched in eventA column will have 2 subset

So Output table will have 2 column similar with causality table eventA will have all the single value and eventB will contain subset of value in evnetA.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that you have a numbers table that stores integers from 0 to a large enough number.  Then, you can do this with "bit-fiddling":

```
select idc.id, n.n, group_concat(nc.team)
from numbers n cross join
     (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from not_connected
      group by id
     ) idc
     on n.n < idc.cnt left join
     (select id, team,
             (@rn := if(@id = id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@id := id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from not_connected cross join
           (select @id := 0, @rn := 0) vars
      order by id, team
     ) nc
     on (n & (1 << nc.rn)) > 0
group by idc.id, n.n;
```

This first generates a row for all the output, a given `id` having 2^n rows where "n" is the number of teams.  Then, each bit is mapped to a team name in the original table.  Finally, a `group by` brings together the values for a given number and id.

You need a numbers table to make this work.  Just generate one large enough for the largest number of teams.  Here is one way to do it:

```
create table numbers as
    select (@rn := @rn + 1) as n
    from not_connected cross join
         (select @rn := 0);
```

Comment: @Kunal2229 . . . Of course this works on string values.  In fact, the team name could be of any type.

Comment: ....according to my table my ID is varchar datatype and after running you query i am not getting subset but grouping of all  with particular ID so that was not i am expecting so please can you see to it again , i will edit my question and will give you exact initial table and output table, please see to it because i am stuck just for it and done with all